# How to return a value from child expect script to parent sh script

Tags: shell, unix, expect

I have a expect script inside a shell script. My problem is I am unable to get a variable value from the child expect script to the shell parent script.

Please find my code below:

```
#!/bin/sh

expect <<- DONE
spawn telnet myemailserver.com imap
expect "* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready."

send "a1 LOGIN myuser mypass\r"
expect "a1 OK LOGIN completed."

send "a2 EXAMINE INBOX\r"
expect "a2 OK EXAMINE completed."

send "a3 SEARCH UNSEEN\r"
expect "a3 OK SEARCH completed."
set results $expect_out(buffer)
set list [split $results "\n"]

send "a4 LOGOUT\r"
expect "Connection closed by foreign host."

spawn echo $list

expect eof
DONE

echo $list
exit 0
```

I found out that the variable list at the last line is empty. Is there a way to pass the value from variable $list to the shell parent script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your here-document is subject to shell variable expansion **before** the script is given to the expect interpreter. The `$list` variable is substituted with nothing (assuming you don't already have a shell variable named list in your program). You need to ensure the here-doc is single quoted (shown below)

Just like working with awk or sed, the shell inter-process communication is performed through passing data along the standard IO channels: the shell script has to capture the output of the expect program:

```
list=$( expect <<'END'
    log_user 0         
    # expect program here
    puts $list
END
)
echo $list
```

Since I'm suppressing normal terminal output of spawned programs with `log_user 0` in order to send only the crucial information back to the shell, you have to replace `spawn echo` with expect's `puts` command.